# Set custom type name in mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, nest

I need to create a document mapping that has a custom name. Currently I have the following mapping for my document on the CreateIndexDescriptor object:

```
.Mappings(m => m
  .Map<MyDocType>(mDetails => mDetails.AutoMap()));
```

Which creates a document mapping called mydoctype. How can I modify this so it creates a document whose type name is my_doctype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NEST 7.x, this is not possible - the document type will be `_doc`, [in line with the roadmap for the removal of mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_schedule_for_removal_of_mapping_types).

In NEST 6.x, you can [specify the type name to use in a few different ways](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/6.x/types-and-relations-inference.html):

1. Using `ElasticsearchTypeAttribute` on the POCO

   ```cs
   [ElasticsearchType(Name = "my_doctype")]
   public class MyDocType{ }
   ```
2. Using `DataContractAttribute` on the POCO

   ```cs
   [DataContract(Name = "my_doctype")]
   public class MyDocType{ }
   ```
3. Using `.DefaultMappingFor<T>()` on `ConnectionSettings`

   ```cs
   var settings = new ConnectionSettings()
       .DefaultMappingFor<MyDocType>(m => m
           .IndexName("my_doc_type_default_index")
           .TypeName("my_doctype")
       );

   var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
   ```

Comment: Thanks again @russ
I ended up using ElasticsearchTypeAttribute